# Is this B&M key SSD SATA or NVME?

Tags: ssd, sata, nvme, m.2

I have a B&M key M.2 SSD which I want to use as an external storage device (via USB) but I'm not sure what technology it uses. My research online says that B&M key SSDs use SATA, but on the label of my SSD it says PCIe GEN3 NVME.

Can anyone help? I've attached an image of the SSD below.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: General rule of thumb: always trust what the hardware says on it _(there are certain instances where double-checking should always be done, such as with widely counterfeited Intel WiFi cards, but in general, that rule of thumb holds true)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key seems to be this one :

[Lenovo 128 GB SSD NVMe PCIe m.2 SSS0R27340 Union Memory with Bracket](https://picclick.co.uk/Lenovo-128-GB-SSD-NVMe-PCIe-m2-SSS0R27340-144475269906.html?refresh=1)

[image]

It is described as :

> UNION MEMORY 128GB SOLID STATE DRIVE SSS0R27340 01FR572. UNION MEMORY 128GB SOLID STATE DRIVE SSS0R27340 01FR572. Condition: New, Features: Removable, Manufacturer Warranty: None, MPN: 01FR572, **Interface: NVME**, Storage Capacity: 128 GB, Compatible With: PC, Storage Format: HDD & SSD, Product Line: union, Drive Type(s) Supported: Internal SSD, SSD (Solid State Drive), Form Factor: 1.8 in, Brand: Union, Type: Internal SSD

Answer : The Interface is indeed NVME. The label is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A M.2 add-in card with B and M keys has access to the common [feature set of B and M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying).

- B: PCIe ×2, SATA, USB 2.0 and 3.0, audio, UIM, HSIC, SSIC, I2C and SMBus
- M: PCIe ×4, SATA and SMBus
- **B+M: PCIe ×2, SATA, SMBus**

The card you have is a PCIe NVMe card. It is very unlikely the label would lie.